# Replace everything on that line after equals sign

Tags: regex, replace, vb.net-2010

Using this in VB 2010:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt")
        Dim foundIndex As Integer = Array.FindIndex(lines, Function(l) l.StartsWith(TextBox1.Text)) 'assuming TextBox1.Text = the part of the line before the =
        lines(foundIndex) = Regex.Replace(lines(foundIndex), "(?<=" & TextBox1.Text & "=)\d+", TextBox2.Text) 'TextBox2.Text is the replacement number
        Stop
        'to rewrite the file:
        'IO.File.WriteAllLines("filename.txt", lines)
    End Sub
End Class
```

...but it keeps adding numbers after equals sign every time i save the text file.

I want it to replace everything on that line after equals sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I executed your code and It works unchanged:

```
Sub Main
     Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\temp\filename.txt")
     lines.Dump()
        Dim foundIndex As Integer = Array.FindIndex(lines, Function(l) l.StartsWith("blah")) 'assuming TextBox1.Text = the part of the line before the =
        foundIndex.Dump()
        lines(foundIndex) = Regex.Replace(lines(foundIndex), "(?<=blah=)[\d.e+]+", "replaced") 'TextBox2.Text is the replacement number
        IO.File.WriteAllLines("c:\temp\filename.txt", lines)
End Sub
```

If the file is

```
test=456
blah=456
blah=just
```

it will become

```
test=456
blah=replaced
blah=just
```

This is as you want it no?

**Update 1**

I replaced

```
"(?<=blah=)\d+"
```

With

```
"(?<=blah=)[\d.]+"
```

**Update 2**

Regarding the issue with strings like "1e+007". The part that matches the string after the "=" is currently [\d.]

Remember that there was a problem with numbers that had the decimal point like 3.25? This was solved by adding the "." to the character class [\d] so it becomes [\d.]
Now anything that is a number "\d" and a "." will match.

The new issue is solved in the same way. Now "e" and "+" should also be matched. Get it? So the character class now becomes [\d.e+]

Give it a go and let me know how it went.

Now it should also be clear how to modify the regex to match "BGS_LOGO.BIK" If you can solve that you understand what's going on.

Comment: No.

The file is like that:

test=3.5 (this number is variable, always different)

and if i try replace it with something like 0.25 then becomes so messed up like this:

test=0.25.5

Comment: Ah, I can reproduce now. Seems that numbers act a bit different. I'll investigate

Comment: I hit another obstacle on the way. this time i need to replace "sIntroSequence=BGS_LOGO.BIK" with "sIntroSequence="

Comment: And your code produced buggy result. I only noticed today. After trying to write "1e+007" after "test=", it becomes like this: "1e+007e+007"...